# Automate and looping through batch script

Tags: linux, bash, automation, batch-processing

I'm new to batch. I  want iterate through a list and use the output content to replace a string in another file.

```
ls -l somefile | grep .txt | awk 'print $4}' | while read file
do
  toreplace="/Team/$file"
  sed 's/dataFile/"$toreplace"/$file/ file2 > /tmp/test.txt
done
```

When I run the code I get the error

```
 sed: 1: "s/dataFile/"$torepla ...": bad flag in substitute command: '$'
```

Example of somefile with which has list of files paths

```
foo/name/xxx/2020-01-01.txt
foo/name/xxx/2020-01-02.txt
foo/name/xxx/2020-01-03.txt
```

However, my desired output is to use the list of file paths in somefile directory to replace a string in another file2 content. Something like this:

```
This is the directory of locations where data from /Team/foo/name/xxx/2020-01-01.txt ............
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your desired outcome, but hopefully this will help you to figure out your problem:

You have three files in a directory:

```
TEAM/foo/name/xxx/2020-01-02.txt
TEAM/foo/name/xxx/2020-01-03.txt
TEAM/foo/name/xxx/2020-01-01.txt
```

And you have another file called `to_be_changed.txt` which contains the text `This is the directory of locations where data from TO_BE_REPLACED ............` and you want to grab the filenames of your three files and insert them into your `to_be_changed.txt` file, you can do it with:

```
while read file
do
  filename="$file"
  sed "s/TO_BE_REPLACED/${filename##*/}/g" to_be_changed.txt >> changed.txt
done < <(find ./TEAM/ -name "*.txt")
```

And you will then have made a file called `changed.txt` which contains:

```
This is the directory of locations where data from 2020-01-02.txt ............
This is the directory of locations where data from 2020-01-03.txt ............
This is the directory of locations where data from 2020-01-01.txt ............
```

Is this what you're trying to achieve? If you need further clarification I'm happy to edit this answer to provide more details/explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -l somefile | grep .txt | awk 'print $4}' | while read file
```

No. No, no, nono.

`ls -l somefile` is only going to show `somefile` unless it's a directory.
(Don't name a directory "somefile".)
If you mean `somefile.txt`, please clarify in your post.

`grep .txt` is going to look through the lines presented for the three characters `txt` preceded by any character (the dot is a regex wildcard). Since you asked for a long listing of `somefile` it shouldn't find any, so nothing should be passed along.

`awk 'print $4}'` is a typo which won't compile. `awk` will crash.

*Keep it simple.* What I suspect you meant was

```
for file in *.txt
```

Then in

```
toreplace="/Team/$file"
sed 's/dataFile/"$toreplace"/$file/ file2 > /tmp/test.txt
```

it's unlear what you expect `$file` to be - `awk`'s $4 from an `ls -l` seems unlikely.
Assuming it's the filenames from the `for` above, then try

```
 sed "s,dataFile,/Team/$file," file2 > /tmp/test.txt
```

Does that help? Correct me as needed. Sorry if I seem harsh.
Welcome to SO. ;)